# excel connection string - relative path

Tags: excel, odbc, connection-string

I have a connection string in an Excel Spreadsheet that links to other spreadsheets. All works well. However, the file and directory are written as absolute. Can this be relative?

There are two files in the same directory `N:\Files\ProjectName\Clients\Alpha\Project.xlsm and N:\Files\ProjectName\Clients\Alpha\Data1.xlsm and on in another directory N:\Files\ProjectName\Clients\Beta\Data2.xlsm`

The connection strings are:

```
DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=N:\Files\ProjectName\Clients\Alpha\Data1.xlsm;DefaultDir=N:\Files\ProjectName\Clients\Alpha
```

and

```
DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=N:\Files\ProjectName\Clients\Beta\Data2.xlsm;DefaultDir=N:\Files\ProjectName\Clients\Beta
```

I want it to work without the n:\ reference?

eg similar to:

`DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=..\Data1.xlsm;DefaultDir=..\Alpha (Because it's in the same directory)` and

```
DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=...\Beta\Data2.xlsm;DefaultDir=...\Beta (because it is in the next directory)
```

Any advice welcomed.

Cheers, Graeme

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213584/relative-instead-of-absolute-paths-in-excel-vba/213602