# define relative path instead of absolute paths in Visual Basic

Tags: relative-path

could someone please help me with how to define relative paths instead of absolute in VB? Or how to declare them in code?

As example:. `**../** oder **~/**`

In order to run an .exe after giving the relative paths in script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative instead of Absolute paths in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213584/relative-instead-of-absolute-paths-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I mean actually in VBScript. How should be the right declaration for relative paths? Or how could it be possible to replace the absolute paths with relative paths?